# Which image generating services don't duplicate copywritten work?

Tags: image-generation, stable-diffusion, recommendation, authorship

Some generative AI services were trained on art that isn't in the public domain and can reproduce that art intentionally or unintentionally. I'm interested in trying out image generators while not accidentally copying someone's art who hasn't intended for it to be used this way. Are there services that are good for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome to GenAI Stack Exchange. This looks like a "shopping list" question that might be a "recommendation question". We don't have yet local guidelines about this kind of question but the common advice is that questions should be specific about what it's required. Related [Are questions asking for recommendation on-topic? In such case what are our guidelines for such questions?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/158/12) (from GenAI Meta), [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) (from Stack Overflow Blog, posted in 2010).

Comment: Is it OK if the source images are copyrighted but under a Creative Commons permissive license such as CC-BY-SA? That means all of Wikimedia Commons and a large part of Flickr.

Comment: Thanks, @Wicket. I didn't realize this might be controversial. Do you have recommendations on how I could ask a similar question in a more acceptable way? I do have questions about how to best use generative AI in an ethical and moral way.

Comment: Good question @NicolasRaoul. It looks like the Creative Commons organization supports generative AI as fair use which makes me rethink this. https://creativecommons.org/2023/02/17/fair-use-training-generative-ai/

Comment: Tom:  The referred blog article in my previous comment recommends, "don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy". Transposing this advice to this question, ask how to know if a GenAI tool might copy someone's art and show what you have tried. You can include in your question asking to include the analysis of one GenAI tool as part of the explanation.

Comment: Wicket: Thanks. Good article. I'd read the question and top answer in the first link. I missed the explanation in the second.

Comment: The updated title removes the notion of consent and copyright. Strictly speaking, all these services *copy someone's art* so I suggest to add more focus in the title.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was answering rev. 3, but the current revision is entirely different. I created a post about this in Meta -> [What should be done with answers that become invalidated b/c the question was rolled back](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/12).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Adobe Firefly](https://firefly.adobe.com/)'s image generation service.

From https://www.adobe.com/sensei/generative-ai/firefly.html:

> As part of Adobe’s effort to address generative AI-related copyright infringement concerns, we are training our initial Firefly model on Adobe Stock images, openly licensed content, and public domain content where copyright has expired. [...] For Adobe Stock contributors, the content is part of Firefly’s training dataset, in accordance with Stock Contributor license agreements.

Note that public domain is just one of many cases where one is allowed to use images to train image generation models. Public domain also doesn't mean that the author has training image generation models in mind.

Disclaimer: I am member of Adobe Research.

Comment: Thanks @franck. I'd read that before and forgotten. Looking at it now, it seems to generate interesting images. Too bad the license restricts commercial use. To some interpretations, that would be any use related to a job and I think it would limit me from using images in social media or in presentations.

Comment: What constitutes "openly licensed work"?  There are a few licenses, such as CC-0 or the WTFPL, that are clearly fair game, but most open licenses have attribution clauses.